# Get hourly data from start time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms, ssms-2012

For example, I have data like this

```
min     max        time                      batch    sensor 
-------------------------------------------------------------------    
10      20         2018-07-20 10:15:00:00      x      abc
15      30         2018-07-20 10:14:00:00      x      abc
15      30         2018-07-20 10:16:00:00      x      abc
|     |    |         |                         |       |
|     |    |         |                         |       |                
20      30         2018-07-20 11:15:00:00      x      abc
```

Now I want hourly data

```
                                                    min   max 
 ------------------------------------------------------------                                                                     
 2018-07-20 10:15:00:00   2018-07-20 11:15:00:00    10    10
```

Comment: you tagged 3 different versions of sql server... which one is it ajay? Also you need to explain your results... it's unclear how you got that result

Comment: sqlserver 2008 version

Comment: i want hourly data    suppose start time 10:45 then 11:45  and so on 11:46: to 12:46 like this

Comment: yes, you stated that, but your results don't make sense. Where did you get 11:15 from? what are all the pipes in the data? what is a batch? What is min and max? Why is max 10 in the result?

Comment: here 30 max value  in that 10

Comment: data bwetween hour and son like   every minitue one line is there

Answer (score 0):

The complexity here is that you are checking an hour-wide window every minute, so your report is 1,440 rows if it is for a full day. Here is a bit of code that can do that:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
-- Create a temporary numbers table to demonstrate its use. 
-- We need numbers up to 24*60-1 (24 hours * 60 minutes -1 for based on zero)

Declare @DailyIntervals int,

SET @DailyIntervals = 24 * 60 - 1
--SELECT @DailyIntervals

-- This calculates the number of recursive inserts needed to reach at least your maximum value
-- NOTE: This is based off of manually inserting your first four values into the table first!

DECLARE @loop int
SET @loop = CEILING(Log(@DailyIntervals,2))-2

Declare @m int
CREATE TABLE ##Nums (i int primary key clustered);

INSERT INTO ##Nums VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4);   -- Seed the table

SET @m = 4

WHILE @loop > 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ##nums SELECT I + @m FROM ##Nums
    SET @m = @@ROWCOUNT * 2 -- max value in table now
    SET @loop = @loop - 1
END

INSERT INTO ##nums Values (0)   -- add the zero value

--SELECT MAX(I) FROM ##Nums

-- Look at July 20th
DECLARE @BeginDt datetime = '2018-07-20'

-- Build a working table of one minute intervals for a full day
WITH hhrs as (
    SELECT Dateadd(MINUTE, i, @BeginDt) as StartTm,
        Dateadd(MINUTE, i+59, @BeginDt) as EndTm
    FROM ##Nums
    WHERE i BETWEEN 0 and @DailyIntervals
    ),

SELECT 
    StartTm,
    EndTm,
    min([Min]) as [Min], 
    max([max]) as [Max]
FROM hhrs h
INNER JOIN MyData m 
    ON m.[Time] Between @StartTm and @EndTm
ORDER BY StartTm

DROP TABLE ##Nums
```